# Elixir Livebook with VIM shortcuts?

Tags: elixir

I love Elixir's Livebook efforts. It is great for quick ideas, tests, ... or in my case still learning about Elixir.

One thing I seriously miss are my VIM ways of navigating through the code. Is any support available?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything available by default, no. The editor used in Livebook is Monaco, for which I found https://github.com/brijeshb42/monaco-vim. There may be others.

Some assembly required.

...by which I mean that you'll probably need to fork Livebook to add it. I can see a number of people being interested, though.

Comment: Thank your the idea. But forking without push back to the main repository is not in my interest. I'm thinking of moving this question into the Livebook repo to possible work on an extra feature.

The idea already is being discussed: https://github.com/livebook-dev/livebook/issues/715